# Parallelize matrix iteration

Tags: r, doparallel

I'm playing with this dummy data to try to parallelize it, so far nI've not been able to achieve the same results as with the non-parallelized code.

Dummy matrix:

```
m <- matrix(1, nrow = 500, ncol = 500)
m[1,1] <- 2 # To check the output keeps rows and columns in same order 
m[2,2] <- 2
m[103,203] <- 2
```

This works as expected:

```
for (i in 1:dim(m)[1]){
  for (j in 1:dim(m)[2]){
    m[i,j] <- m[i,j] + 1
  } 
}
```

This doesn't work as expected:

```
cl <- makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK")
registerDoParallel(cl)
output <- foreach(i=1:dim(m)[1]) %dopar% {
  df <- data.frame()
  for( j in 1:dim(m)[2]){
    df[i,j] <- m[i,j] + 1
  }
  df
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

This neither:

```
cl <- makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK")
registerDoParallel(cl)
output <- foreach(i=1:dim(m)[1],.combine='cbind' ) %:% 
  foreach (j=1:dim(m)[2], .combine='c') %do% {
    m[i,j] <- m[i,j] + 1
  }
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: You should consider how parallelization works: You give input to the workers and they give the result back. Workers don't know the results from other workers. In practice, this means that you split the total input, the workers do their job, and then you combine their results to get the total result.

Comment: Also, your example is not a good one. You would never use your double `for` loop in R. You would just do `m <- m +1` which is much faster. Parallelization will actually be much slower than your double `for` loop because of overhead.

Comment: So, which is the best solution to iterate across a big matrix.

Comment: @HeyHoLetsGo thinking of way to not iterate. What are you exactly calculating?